# Pass a value from a textbox into a query to perform a calculation in C#

Tags: c#

I am am trying to pass a value from a textbox into an sql query to find the amount of times the entered number appears in the database. I'm new to C# programming and any help would be much appreaciated :)

My SQL query is scalar and looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(WinNo01) AS CountOfball1
FROM tblLotto
GROUP BY WinNo01
HAVING WinNo01 = @num
```

And my code is this:

```
namespace Assessment2
{
    public partial class Statistics : Form
    {
        public Statistics()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int amount = 0;
            amount = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);            

            label2.Text = "1st position appearances : " + tblLottoTableAdapter.StatisticRow01(amount).ToString();                             
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: I can get the query to work by taking out the @num and putting in a value but I need it to read in the value from the text box. I am very green so please give me simple answers :)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&safe=off&q=c%23+reading+data+from+database&oq=c%23+reading+data+from+data&gs_l=serp.3.0.0l2j0i22i30l8.3806.4951.0.5472.10.5.0.5.5.0.150.556.3j2.5.0.cshsj%2Cj%3Dbottom%2Cjnum%3D2%2Cjlen%3D3%2Cjprob%3D-08...0...1c.1.25.serp-shj..0.10.641.BUK2y5_Hu1Q

Comment: Assuming you're using an `SqlCommand` you could do something like: `command.Parameters["@num"].Value = amount;`.

Answer (score 1):

This article on MSDN may be of help to you:

[Store the TextBox values in SQL Table in C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d6e77f68-270d-4761-9304-1283b19cb5f8/store-the-textbox-values-in-sql-table-in-c)

So with the above in mind, you could do this:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (@MyValue)";
SqlCommand cmd = new Sqlcommand(query, sqlConn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@MyValue", SqlDbType.Varcharm, 50).Value = myTextBox.Text;
cmd.Connection.Open();
try
{
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int amount;
    if(int.TryParse(textBox1.Text,out amount))
    {
        using (var com = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("your connection string").CreateCommand())
        {
            com.CommandText = @"SELECT COUNT(WinNo01) AS CountOfball1
                            FROM tblLotto
                            GROUP BY WinNo01
                            HAVING WinNo01 = @num";
            com.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("num", amount));
            com.Connection.Open();
            try
            {
                int result = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());
                label2.Text = result.ToString();
            }
            finally 
            {
                com.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mecek, I have tried this but as I run the button click after I have entered the value I get the error "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible" any idea why that may be happening??

Comment: Your connection string may be incorrect or you have a connection problem with SqlServer instance, check your connection, and check if your SqlServer instance is running